# How to replace storyboard segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm kinda confused with the storyboards. I've got my storyboard like this:

[image: screen shot of storyboard]

Now I want to change the link between "Tab Bar Controller" and "Main Scroll View". Instead I want to put the white "View Controller" and on the "View Controller" I want to place a button and when you click on the button it gets to the "Main Scroll View". How can I do this in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the segue.  Drag a navigationController into storyboard, and make that the view that replaces your current mainScrollView in your tabBarViewController.  When you drag a nvigationController in, it will pull a viewController with it as a rootView.  Delete that.  Control-click and drag from the new navigation controller to your white viewController, and select "root view".  Place the button in your white viewController.  Control-click and drag from the button to the mainScrollViewController, and select "push".